# Выводит ошибку TypeError: MainWindow.find_directory() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, tkinter

Хочу сделать программу более удобной - чтобы функция выполнялась не только по нажатию кнопки, но и при нажатии Enter. Используя .bind выдает такую ошибку 'TypeError: MainWindow.find_directory() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given'. Не могу понять, в чем дело, ведь при нажатии кнопки все работает нормально.
Объявляю класс MainWindow:

```
class MainWindow(Tk):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

# Расположение кнопок, текста и т.д.
def initUI(self):
    self.title("Поиск документации на сервере")
    self.geometry('800x500')
    self.centerWindow(800, 500)
```

Добавляю кнопку и событие для запуска метода:

```
    find_button = Button(self, text="Найти", cursor="hand2", command=self.find_directory)
    find_button.place(x=50, y=130)
    self.bind('<space>', self.find_directory)
```

А вот и сам метод класса:

```
    def find_directory(self):
    try:
        self.frame_of_name_directory.place_forget()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    try:
        self.self.open_button.place_forget()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Comment: В функцию ещё передаётся событие, поэтому ´ def find_directory(self,event)’

Comment: @СергейКох Разве не в .bind передается 2 значения: событие и функция, которая при этом вызывается? А уже функция просто выполняется

Comment: "Поскольку tkinter автоматически передает объект события, вам нужно, чтобы он принял этот аргумент, но вам не нужно передавать этот аргумент явно." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040202/tkinter-pass-event-to-a-function#:~:text=1-,When%20you%20call,-bind%2C%20you%20must

Comment: @СергейКох Спасибо, добавил в функцию ´ def find_directory(self,event)’, и просто выполняю внутри bar = event. Теперь при нажатии <space> функция срабатывает, но это повлекло за собой другую проблему - теперь при нажатии кнопки find_button функция работает не совсем корректно.

Comment: Создайте, пожалуйста, новый вопрос с минимальным кодом воспроизводящем проблему.